# How can you stop "Verification required" when installing free apps?

Tags: ios-appstore

Whenever I install a free app on my iPad, this message appears:

> **Verification required**
>   Before you can make purchases, you must tap continue to sign in, then verify your payment info.

What does it mean? How can I stop it?

Comment: Does it happen **each time** you install an App? Does it happen only with free apps? Did you ever finished the verification process?

Answer (score 3):

Generally verification comes up for one of two reasons:

- Your previously-supplied payment information failed for your last purchase
- You are using a device which has never purchased (or downloaded, for free apps) anything from the App Store with your account before.

Most likely it is the second one. Going through the payment verification process does not charge your payment method, it simply verifies it is valid. Once completed you can complete the download of your free app.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution to the verification problem.

1. Go to your account.
2. For the list of credit cards, select **None**.
3. Save and you can start downloading without being  charged.

Comment: Could you be more specific for step 1? In iTunes? On Apple ID website? On iOS device?